# Cocos2dx v3.4 Windows Universal App fails Windows Certification Tests

Tags: cocos2d-x, libcurl, win-universal-app

Cocos2dx v3.4 Windows Universal App fails Windows Certification Tests for Windows Store 8.1. I do not have the windows update KB2976978 installed. I have created a new cocos project and built it for Windows Store Release in VS Professional Update 4. It fails on libcurl. I have tried checking the boxs in the app manifest for internet (Client) and also the Internet (Client & Server) along with the Private networks.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the error:

```
API FormatMessageA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. libcurl.dll calls this API.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [cocos2d-x boards](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/v3-4-windows-universal-app-fails-windows-certification-tests-for-windows-store-app/20634) this is a known issue that should be fixed in current versions on github.

Pull from https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x2 and make sure to do

```
git submodule update --init 
./download-deps.py
```

Comment: Discussed here http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/v3-4-windows-universal-app-fails-windows-certification-tests-for-windows-store-app/20634/5